# Using sprites with Weasyprint

Tags: html, css, pdf, sprite, weasyprint

I'm trying to create .pdf files from a php/html script with `weasyprint`.

When opening my script in a browser, everything appears well. But when I generate the .pdf with weasyprint and open it, my sprite is not rendered as it should be.

Example : 
[image: normal]
becomes
[image: weasyprint]

Here is a sample of properties applied to a `<span>` to display the sprite :

```
.spr0 {
    background-image: url(/images/sprite_0.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.spr_star5 {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 14px;
}
```

Is there some properties that `weasyprint` doesn't accept, so that's why my sprite isn't well displayed?